# select distinct column count in Aggregation query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**================= Edited for simple problem statement start ================**

```
db.t2.insert({_id:1,account:"abc",vendor:"amazon"});
db.t2.insert({_id:2,account:"abc",vendor:"overstock"});
db.t2.insert({_id:3,account:"abc",vendor:"overstock"});
```

Now you have to find out count of unique vendors group by account.
Here it will show answer is

```
{ "_id" : "abc", "number" : 2 }
```

Possible solutions are

```
db.t2.aggregate(
{ $group : { _id : { "z" : "$z", "v" : "$v" }} },
{ $group : { _id : "$_id.z", number : { $sum : 1 } } }
);
```

Or just add to set and then count it But Assume you have millions records, then how effectively like sql statement you can achieve the same ?

```
select count(distinct(vendor)) from t group by account
```

**=================== Problem statement ends ============================**

So i did like following...

```
db.t.insert({_id:1,v:"xyz",z:1});
db.t.insert({_id:3,v:"123",z:1});
db.t.insert({_id:5,v:"xyz",z:1});
```

Now I wants to execute following query

```
select count(distinct(v)) from t group by z;
```

So the result expected is for z = 1 distinct values are xyz & 123

```
{ "_id" : 1, "number" : 2 }
```

I can execute following and get the result as above.

```
db.t.aggregate(
{ $group : { _id : { "z" : "$z", "v" : "$v" } } },
{ $group : { _id : "$_id.z", number : { $sum : 1 } } }
);
```

But I don't wants to execute the $group twice. Because lets say i have bigger collection, then first it will do group by and whatever intermediate **result will be stored in memory till 2nd group by applies**. Which is exactly what i wants to avoid.

Comment: I don't get it. Why not just group on "z" in the first place? You're discarding the "number" result from the earlier group anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn Please see the records inserted carefully. I've added v:"xyz", record twice. So if i just count , then records will be 3. Did you get it ?

Comment: And geez I think I did, I I think I have enough experience to know that I did. What I was trying to avoid was the class of answers you have received. Which are correct ( at least one ) but nothing more than the obvious I stated ( note the upvotes ) and when you could have just realized your mistake and closed the question. It's a simple solve.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am not questioning about your experience level. Its just simple problem but how effectively you solve.

Lets say Following are the records 

db.t2.insert({_id:1,account:"abc",vendor:"amazon"});
db.t2.insert({_id:2,account:"abc",vendor:"overstock"});
db.t2.insert({_id:3,account:"abc",vendor:"overstock"});

Now you have to find out count of unique vendors group by account.
Here it will show answer is 
{ "_id" : "abc", "number" : 2 }

Comment: Will you make up your mind. Your question is wrong. There are `2` values for "xyz" and `1` value for 123. If you want both then the correct result is `3` and not `2` unless you filter out "distinct" values beforehand. Which is what you are doing.

Comment: @NeilLunn dude, can you please check the problem statement now, I think i've tried to simplify it.

Comment: Still baffled why you do not see that grouping on values to "amazon" and "otherstock" as distinct values "first" is not what you need to do. There is no possible function in an efficient way that can say "just count amazon as 1" . You are confusing inexperienced people to provide an answer where the obvious is present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate as below:

- `Group` by `z` and accumulate all the values of `v` using the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)
  operator, to maintain unique lists of `v`, per group.
- `Project` the `number` field as the [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) of the `number` array.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$z","number":{$addToSet:"$v"}}},
{$project:{"number":{$size:"$number"}}}
])
```

o/p: `{ "_id" : 1, "number" : 2 }`

Comment: BatScream  Why you add values in temporary array? Let's say this is the data contains visits and its in millions, Would you go with temporary array which will store all the distinct values ?

Comment: @MayurKataria because it is wrong as you were told earlier.